# xml handling multiple variables with xmlHttp.open

Tags: javascript, php, xml

I cannot echo two variables when sent to the server with `xmlHttp.open`. I understand that I need to use `&` to seperate the variables, but I am getting a server response error and no output. The code works fine if just the `foo` variable is sent. I think it must be a simple error I just need another set of eyes on.

Javascript File:

```
var foo = "foo" 
var bar = "bar"

xmlHttp.open("GET", "update.php?foo=" + foo+ "&bar=" + bar, true);
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse;
xmlHttp.send(null);
```

update.php:

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/xml');
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>';

echo '<response>';
    $foo= $_GET['foo'];
    $bar= $_GET['bar'];
    echo 'Variable foo: ' . $foo. ' Variable bar ' . $bar; // Server response error and no output
echo '</response>';

?>
```

Comment: What response is the server giving back? How is the querystring build. You can watch this in the sources/network tab of your dev tool (hotkey F12).

Comment: You have to name the error you get. Error code, Error Message, Protocol, Logfile excerpts, the full HTTP Request, the full HTTP response. Not that you need to add all of these, but you should at least provide the network communication between your browser and your server and at the very minimum provide the error message and code. Also you should name the browser you're using (incl. the version). - Additionally: https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+debug+xmlHttp+site%3Astackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0):

Did you instantiate the xmlHttp object.

```js
var foo = "foo",
  bar = "bar",
  xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();


xmlHttp.open("GET", "update.php?foo=" + foo + "&bar=" + bar, true);
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse;
xmlHttp.send(null);
```

Alternately I would suggest using JQuery to get around the fact that IE and others use different object constructions.

```js
$.get('/update.php', {foo:foo,bar:bar}, function(result) {
  console.log(result);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```